# how to save a dynamic string?

Tags: java, android

In my app I get the current time and convert it to a string.

as you see this string will be changed every time I open the activity But I want to save this time string in a static string which if I went back to this activity I could show it to user.

This is my code so far:

```
    Time now = new Time();
    now.setToNow();
    String str = now.toString().substring(0, 15);
    textview.setText(str);
```

Actually I have a listview that has items.
this time string is in `listview.onitemclicklistener` and I want to whenever that item is created I save the time and when users clicked on that I show that time in second activity.
For example if user created the item in listview in two days ago, when clicks on that Item I show two days ago date and time:

This my code with more details:

first activity:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Time now = new Time();
            now.setToNow();
            String timedate = now.toString().substring(0, 15);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Albums.this, AlbumPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("extra", timedate);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

second activity:

```
String str = getIntent().getExtras().getString("extra");
textview.setText(str);
```

in this way when I click on each Item it just shows the current time not the time that Item is created (my listview is dynamic an user can add or delete items).

Comment: Do you want it to always show the first time you ran this app?  The time the activity was created?  Something else?

Comment: I think you can use SharedPreferences for the same.

Comment: Use Shared Preferences

Comment: @GabeSechan actually this code is in an onClickListener and I want to save the time that button clicked.

Comment: @pratik I don't think so. can you give me an example?

Comment: if you don't want this value across two launches of your application then avoid using shared preferences, Use a static string variable, assign its value in onStart() call back, that way the time value will be reset every time your activity is launched. and if you want this value in the next sucessive launch of your APP then write the value(into shared prefs) of the static variable in onDestroy call back

Answer (score 0):

Add below code where you want to save current time.

> list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>
> ```
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
>                 long arg3) {
> //declare pref editor 
>       SharedPreferences prefs; 
>       SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
>       prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
>
>
>       String  savedTime=prefs.getString("time", "");
>
>       //now check the value of shared pref and apply the condition like this
>       if(savedTime.isEmpty()) {
>           //set time if time is not set 
>           prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
>           Time now = new Time();
>           now.setToNow();
>           String str = now.toString().substring(0, 15);
>           prefsEditor.putString("time", str);
>           prefsEditor.commit();
> Intent intent=new Intent(this, class2.class);
> startActivity(intent);
>
>       }
>       else {
>           //perform your action here if time is already set
> Intent intent=new Intent(this, class2.class);
> startActivity(intent);
>       }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
     SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
Editor editor = pref.edit();
    Time now = new Time();
    now.setToNow();
    String str = now.toString().substring(0, 15);
    editor.putString("key_name", str); 
    editor.commit();
    textview.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your Activity's **onPause or onDestroy**

```
  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF",
   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
   Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
   Time now = new Time();
   now.setToNow();
    String str = now.toString().substring(0, 15);
   editor.putString("time", str); 
   editor.commit();
```

then to Retrieve it use the following code in **onStart()** method

```
 SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF",
   Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
 String time = sharedpreferences.getString("time" "default_value");
```